# Why is the representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)$ defined in this way irreducible?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\{h=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 
\end{bmatrix},e = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},f = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\}$ be the canonical basis of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)$ and consider the linear representation $$\pi:\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C) \to \text{End}(V),$$

where $V=\text{Span}\{v_0,\dots, v_{n+1}\}$ (a $n+1$ dimensional vector space), defined on the basis $\{h,e,f\}$ by

$$\pi(h)v_i=(n-2i)v_i,$$ $$\pi(e)v_i=i(n-i+1)v_{i-1},$$ $$\pi(f)v_i=v_{i+1},$$

for $i=0,1,\dots,n$ with the convention that $v_{-1}=v_{n+1}=0$. It is not hard to check that $\pi$ preserves the Lie brackets.

Now, I would like to show $\pi$ defined in this way is irreducible from definition. Let $U\subset V$ be a nonzero $\pi$-invariant subspace. If I could prove that at least one of the vectors $\{v_0,\dots,v_n \}$ is in $U$, then I can use the relations $\pi(e)v_i=i(n-i+1)v_{i-1},\pi(f)v_i=v_{i+1}$ to conclude that all of $\{v_0,\dots,v_n\}$ are in $U$, which forces $U=V$.

But how do we prove that $U$ contains at least one of $\{v_0,\dots,v_n \}$? I guess we have to use $\pi(h)v_i=(n-2i)v_i$ in some way?

---

This is from Lie groups: Beyond an introduction by Knapp, page 64. It seems that the author does not assume any advanced theory for this verification. The notion of weight (vectors) has not been introduced at this point.

Comment: Hint: a finite-dimensional repn contains a highest-weight vector (and lowest-weight). A proper subrepn would also... I think this simple fact is needed to make this discussion intelligible...

Comment: @paulgarrett Thanks, but is there a direct and elementary proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is yet another argument, which is fairly direct and which is repeated numerous times, in essentially this form, throughout representation theory. The fact from linear algebra that is crucial is this: if you have a linear operator $T$ acting on a $k$-dimensional vector space $V$ and the eigenvalues for $T$ are all distinct, with eigenvectors $v_1,\dots,v_k$, then *any* eigenvector for $T$ is a non-zero multiple of one of the $v_i$'s.

If you suppose $U$ is a non-zero $\pi$-invariant subspace, then since $\mathbf{C}$ is algebraically closed (this is not crucial, but is quick), $U$ contains an eigenvector for the operator $\pi(h)$. Since $\pi(h)$ acts diagonalizable on $V$ with eigenvectors $v_0,v_1,\dots,v_{n+1}$ of *distinct* eigenvalues $n,n-2,\dots,-n+2,-n$, *any* eigenvector for $\pi(h)$ in $V$ must be a non-zero multiple of some $v_i$. Thus $U$ contains some $v_i$, and the formulas for $\pi(e)$ and $\pi(f)$ show that $U$ contains *all* of $v_0,\dots,v_{n+1}$ and is hence equal to $V$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following adaptation/recapitulation of some basic results suits:

Suppose $W$ is a proper subrepresentation. Let $v=c_1v_1+\ldots+c_nv_n$ be a shortest (non-zero) linear combination of weight vectors $v_i$ lying inside $W$. Let $i_o$ be the lowest index such that $c_{i_o}\not=0$. Then (EDIT) unless already $\pi(h)(v)=(n-2i_o)v$, in which case $v=v_{i_o}$, the difference $v'=\pi(h)(v)-(n-2i_o)v$ is non-zero, is still in $W$, and is a shorter linear combination of weight vectors. (EDIT2) In formulas:
$$
\pi(h)(v) - (n-2i_o)v \;=\; \sum_i c_i(n-2i)v_i - \sum_i c_i(n-2i_o)v_i
$$
$$
\;=\; \sum_{i\not=i_o} c_i((n-2i)-(n-2i_o))v_i
\;=\; \sum_{i\not=i_o} (2i_o-2i) v_i
$$
Thus, no $v_i$ not already occurring in the linear combination occurs in the image, and $v_{i_o}$ no longer occurs.

Then since the formulas show that any one of the weight vectors generate the whole thing, we're done.

Comment: Sorry, why is $v'=\pi(h)(v)-(n-2i_o)v$ necessarily shorter? I can only see the coefficent before $v_{i_0}$ get cancelled, but $v'$ could have more nonzero terms when expressed in terms of $v_0,\dots v_n$

Comment: Thanks very much! Stephen's answer seems to be more direct to me, though.

Comment: @NoOne, I think it is an operationally equivalent way of invoking "basis of eigenvectors" for some operator... You'd want to see these as "the same". :)

Comment: @NoOne, also, here is an example where "logical order" is not really the point. Basic things have lots of different proofs, depending on fairly capricious choices of set-up. And, _after_ a certain point, one no longer usefully thinks of those artifacts. An extreme case is in basic complex analysis, where one (hopefully as early as possible!) proves the Cauchy theorem, so we know that complex differentiable, complex analytic, and satisfying Cauchy-Riemann equations are all equivalent. And then we just call such functions "holomorphic"... allowing/using any one of the _characterizations_... :)